# In Mongodb, db.collectionName.findOne().fieldName gives output but db.collectionName.find().fieldName does not give output

Tags: mongodb

I am Learning MongoDB. I am confused by the following:

`db.collectionName.findOne({_id: "uniqueid"}).fieldName` 
gives output 
but,
`db.collectionName.find({_id: "uniqueid"}).fieldName`
does not give output

```
db.patients.findOne({name : "Max"}).diseaseSummary
[ "cold", "broken  nail" ]
db.patients.find({name : "Max"}).diseaseSummary
```

Why am I not getting same output with `find()` and if this is wrong, how can I access the field of `find()` query?

Comment: I've updated the formatting a bit to separate individual chunks of the question.

Answer (score 0):

`find()` method is returning an `array`, so you can't use `array.fieldName`, it should be `array[index].fieldName`

while `findOne()` is returning an `object`

so you need to use array of index 0 to get your data

```
db.collectionName.find({_id: "uniqueid"})[0].fieldName
```

hope it helps